# How to find duplicate id in table and display list of that

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am importing the data from a table to another table with same structure only one changes in these two table i add a primary key in new table. So i want to find out the duplicate id my table . I am using below query for find out but this did not work . But the same query are working in `mysql` `sybase` . What i need to change in the blow query .

```
SELECT RPSID,COUNT(1) AS n 
FROM Rpserv 
GROUP BY RPSID 
HAVING n>1 ORDER BY RPSID DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT RPSID, COUNT(*) AS n 
    FROM Rpserv 
    GROUP BY RPSID 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1 
    ORDER BY RPSID DESC
```